# Check what 'this' references in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm learning dojo and having some trouble with the context of events.  What I'd really like to know is if there is a way to find out at a given point what `this` is pointing to.  For example, in c# I could just put in a break point and easily see that `this` referenced as well as it's state.  I've tried just putting in something like:

`alert(this)`

but that just gives me `[object Object]`.

Could anyone suggest how I can better debug my code to find out at a given time exactly what object `this` is pointing to?

Thanks very much

Comment: You can put `debugger;` in your JS - this will set a breakpoint and halt execution if you have a debugger open (e.g. dev tools in chrome). You can then browse the variables, including `this`.

Comment: @UpTheCreek great tip, combined with the advice below this is exactly what I was after, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) or Developer Tools in Chrome to debug your Javascript code.

[image]

Comment: Wow, to think I've had firefug all this time (having used the net panel) and never looked at the script panel.  Exactly what I needed, thanks!